GRUB disappeared in Ubuntu 24.04
After updating my Ubuntu from 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04, my GRUB disappeared.
There's no way to find it. Have other Ubuntu users had this problem?

see this answer  https://askubuntu.com/a/1525893/1698042

Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

When logged in, open a terminal and type sudo cat /etc/default/gruib and post the result by editing your question please.

I had Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot with Windows. When I turned my computer on, GRUB was displaying list of systems and other software to run. Few days ago I upgraded to 24.04 and GRUB disappeared. Only Ubuntu was booting.
I resolved the issue by reading file /etc/default/grub. In it there is a reference to info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'. This page has useful information on how to fix GRUB configuration.
To make this story short, file /boot/grub/grub.cfg is telling GRUB what to do, but it is quite complicated to read (at least for me it was). That is why there is a program called grub-mkconfig that is creating GRUB config file when provided different file with required values, i.e. /etc/default/grub.
So I edited /etc/default/grub by changing GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden to GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu. Run sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg. And then rebooted the system.
